# Why does the upper table overlap the lower figure-lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, savefig

Question is a figure & table together from different axes.

On the one hand, its fine in figure window shows below, after `constrained_layout=True` is added:

[image]

On the other hand, the lower-lines and upper-table overlapped after save it to picture. `plt.savefit("path+fig.png", bbox_index='tight)`

[image]

Comment: set the figsize

Comment: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10)) or some suitable value.

Comment: @abhilb  seems don't work. `Figure` is stretched longer, still overlapped with `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned how to avoid the problem that `lines` and `tables` overlapped each other.(yet not fully understand)

```py
plt.savefig('path+name.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.tight_layout()
```

instead of

```py
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('path+name.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

---

---

- If `plt.tight_Layout()` is before `plt.savefig()`, the result is `lines` are **tight** only, excluding `tables`(tables very likely will be overlapped), so does the pictures created by `plt.savefig()`;
- if we set `plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True` instead of `plt.tight_layout()`. Well, `lines` and `tables` is fine in the `figure window`, however, the `tables` are overlapped still in the picture created by `plt.savefig()`;
- if we move `plt.savefig()`,

> - `plt.tight_layout()` can only zoom the `lines` excluding `tables`;

> - `plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout']=True` can zoom both of `lines` and `tables` in the `figure` window.